# Looping within a loop in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, reactstrap

I am currently building a client management system web application for a college project. Within this, I have a user profile component where the user can view their information (e.g. company name, first name) and edit this information when you clicked one. I want to go about simplifying it because I think it's badly written and confusing. I would love some input on how to go about doing this.

Here's how I do it right now:

```
{
  data.length <= 0
  ? <IsLoading />
  : data.filter(data => data._id === projectId).map(data => (
    <div key={data.id} className="viewUser">
      <div className="viewUserHeading">
        <div id="viewBoxHeading" className="viewUserContactView">
          <div
            onClick={() => this.editUser(data.id, 41)}
            className="viewUserContactViewLink"
          >
            <h2 className="viewUserContactViewData">{data.name}</h2>
            <FeatherIcon className="viewUserContactViewLinkEdit" icon="edit" />
          </div>
      </div>
      <div id="editBoxHeading" className="viewUserContactEdit">
          <Input 
            type="text"
            onChange={e => this.setState({ updateToApply: e.target.value, updateCurrent: data.name, updateToField: "name" })}
            placeholder={data.name}
          >         
          </Input>
          <FeatherIcon 
            color="success" 
            className="viewUserContactCheck" 
            icon="check"
            onClick={() => this.editUser(data.id, 42)} 
          />
        </div>               
      </div>
    ))
  }
```

In this case, it shows the name, and when I click it, I can edit and change it. I have done this for each data value (so 5) and used a different id for each.

I am hoping to achieve something like this within the current loop

```
data.foreach(data.value) {
  <div className={data.id}>
    {data.field: data.value}
</div>
}
```

This way I can automate my function and clean up half my component. It would be great to get input on this or get any other suggestions.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I could see one loop on the 4th line: `.map(data => (`, but unable to fund the inner loop. Can you clarify?